# Scroll to specific element Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `Selenium` with `Java` and `ChromeDriver` to run few scripts on a website. I want to scroll the driver or the page to an specific element located on the page. It might be visible. I understand that with a `JavascripExecutor` it's possible, but so far the way I'm doing it I can only scroll certain "spaces".
Here is what I have:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to scroll to specific element, you should try using [`scrollIntoView(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) as below :-

```
//Find that specific element first 
WebElement element = driver.findElement(..);

//Now scroll to this element 
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I was looking for.