# How to keyPress Page Down multiple times in selenium WebDriver using java?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to scroll down using Robot class in Selenium WebDriver using Java. I have figured out that in order to access the required element in the webpage I have to press `PgDn` button 28 times. Hence, I want to press `PgDn` button 28 times using Robot class. The code I wrote to do this is given below:

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    for(int i=0; i<29; i++) {
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
    }

} catch (AWTException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I used a for loop to do this but it is not working. The `PgDn` KeyEvent is getting executed only once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to specific element Selenium WebDriver Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176245/scroll-to-specific-element-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: Your method is not very efficient and is very fragile. Just grab the desired element and scroll to it.

Comment: Yes, Jeff. This is another lucrative solution for sure. I did not know about this procedure before. I appreciate your support. I have another question for you though. Would you please tell me that why is the procedure of using a for loop is fragile or inefficient according to you? I mean what are the drawbacks compared to the procedure that you suggested?

Comment: @JeffC - The solution that you suggested is unfortunately not working as the driver is unable to locate the required element using driver.findElement()

Hence, jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element) is not working.

First it is required to scroll down to the required part of the page where the required element could be located. Then only WebElement element = driver.findElement(..) will work.

In this case I am being shown the below exception:

Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='news-feed']/section[28]/article/section/a/div/h1"}

Comment: The `for` loop is fragile because what if the page layout changes and the desired element is no longer available at 28? Screen resolution, other devices, maybe even other browsers will likely not be the same either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main issue with this approach is that it is fragile in that if the page content or layout or screen resolution or browser/device changes, that will likely break this script.

I would approach it like this:

1. Load the page
2. Search for the element
3. Scroll down and goto 2

Basically you repeatedly scroll down and search for the element until it is found or you reach the bottom of the page.

The script

```
int currentHeight = 1;
int lastHeight = 0;
boolean endOfPage = false;
while (!isElementPresent(locator) && !endOfPage)
{
    currentHeight = scrollDown();
    endOfPage = currentHeight == lastHeight;
}
if (!endOfPage)
{
    // do something with the desired element
}
else
{
    // log error that the element was not found before reaching end of page
}
```

Support functions

```
public static int scrollDown()
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");

    return (int) (long) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight;");
}

public static boolean isElementPresent(By locator)
{
    return !driver.findElements(locator).isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: Hello Jeff, ya you were absolutely right with your view point. My code with the for loop was not working when in the next day I tried to reproduce the issue. This was because the page layout changed due to some deployment. Thank you for your valuable experienced feedback regarding this issue.

Comment: Hello Jeff, Thank you very much as the solution you gave for my problem is absolutely right and the piece of code you provided worked absolutely fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to add key release also. Below code might give you some idea.

```
try
{
    Robot robot=new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

    robot.mousePress(KeyEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    robot.mouseRelease(KeyEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
catch(Exception e)
{}
```

Hope this helps. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try add a keyRelease after the keyPress

```
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_DOWN);
```

Comment: Hello Stefan. My code is working fine just by adding keyRelease. My appreciations for your help. I have another question though for this issue. In case of this kind of problems where I might have to use a loop, is it always a necessity to add keyRelease after every keyPress?

Comment: Glad to have helped you and please accept the answer if you are happy.. The reason for this is that javascript on the page could potentially trigger on either down or release events and that is why you have to send them both but should not be a problem to have them in a loop. If your page are catching a down or release event you might have to add some sleep timers as your javascript code have to finish executing before next cycle of keys pressed.

Answer (score 0):

My code is working fine just by adding keyRelease after the keyPress. I appreciate all of yours comments to help me regarding this.